# JavaScript is not Running/Working/Loading on my website

Tags: javascript

If I use the script tag or link the file the js does not Run if it is a problem with the js here is my code.

```
$("img").on("contextmenu", function (e) {
    return false;
});

$("img").mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});


const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");


/* Toggle mobile menu */
function toggleMenu() {
    if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
        menu.classList.remove("active");
        toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>";
    } else {
        menu.classList.add("active");
        toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";
    }
}



/* Event Listeners */
toggle.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu, false);
for (let item of items) {
    if (item.querySelector(".submenu")) {
        item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
    }
    item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleItem, false);
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeSubmenu, false);
```

I have the disabled cache to and I have reloaded and Copied the exact file name to my script tag that links the javascript.
And my HTML. Because it might be a problem here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <!-- basic -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <!-- mobile metas -->
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
   <!-- site metas -->
   <title>Upright Code - Hire Me Coder</title>
   <meta name="description" content="Hire Me, I am a Coder, Web and coding tutorials" />
   <meta name="keywords"
      content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript, Hire Coder, Hire, Code, Coder, Coding Lessons, Lessons on HTML, Lessons on CSS" />
   <meta name="author" content="--------" />
   <!-- Awsome Font -->
   <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/82298f2f89.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


   <!-- Javascript js -->
   <script src="js\Main_Javascript.js" defer></script>




   <!-- style css -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <!-- fevicon -->
   <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.png" type="image/png" />
   <!-- Tweaks for older IEs-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css"
      media="screen">
   </head>
<body>
<!--
   <script>
      window.location.replace("https://uprightcode.com/comming-soon");
</script>
-->

<nav>
   <ul class="menu">
      <li class="logo"><a href="https://uprightcode.com/">Upright Code</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="https://uprightcode.com/">Home</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#plans">Plans</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="https://uprightcode.com/Lessons">Lessons</a>
      </li>
   <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<section class="hero">
   <div class="hero-content">
      <h1 class="hero-title">
         Discover the World
      </h1>
      <h2 class="hero-subtitle">
         We offer the best adventure holidays and tailor-made trips!
      </h2>
      <button type="button" class="hero-button" onclick="location.href='tours.html'">
         Search for tours &raquo;
      </button>
   </div>
</section>
<img src="images/garfield-movie.webp">
</body>
</html>
<script>
  setTimeout(function () {   console.clear(); }, 10000);
</script>
```

I put where the js is my full path to that is
/uprightcode/js/Main_Javascript.js

Comment: where is the relevant HTML? Have you checked to the console to see if that gives an error

Comment: I am going to put that in and I haven't checked it. Found one error Main_Javascript.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Main_Javascript.js:1

Comment: You're using jQuery but you haven't loaded jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load jquery. Add this in HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```